# Tableau Using Filter Action to change Parameter value

Tags: tableau-api

Is it possible in a Dashboard to apply a date range filter to a field, let's call it `Date`, to get min(Date) and max(Date) values and pass them to two parameters, respectively called `Start Date` and `End Date`?

I've searched online but I couldn't find anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

Link to Tableau community with attached Tableau example:
https://community.tableau.com/ideas/8657

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. This is a long-standing feature request that for some reason is not being implemented yet. They refer to it as [Dynamic parameters](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/1178). The idea is currently under review, since 2012.

In my case I ended up removing the time range filter completely and using the parameters controller directly as user date inputs.